# Using MapThread and ReplaceAll together

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I am trying to carry out some operations on the elements of `dataset2`, which is an 11 x 14 x 6 dimensional array:

I have a function, `CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]` defined in Mathematica using something of the form

```
CDexpr2[St_,LD_,hL_]:=...
```

and a set of rules defined by

```
rules = {num -> 1, num -> 2, num -> 3, num -> 4, num -> 5, num -> 6, num -> 7, num -> 8, num -> 9, num -> 10, num -> 11};
```

and essentially I would like to evaluate `CDexpr2` on the information inside `dataset2` by applying it to the appropriate columns. The details are a bit tedious, so I will just copy my code here, which should work with any random `dataset2` of the right size and dimensions.

```
list = ConstantArray[
 HoldForm[With[{St = dataset2[[1]][[;; , 2]]}, 
     CDexpr2[St, LD, hL]] /. LD -> dataset2[[num]][[;; , 3]] /. 
   hL -> dataset2[[num]][[;; , 4]]], 11]
```

Since I have used `HoldForm`, the result is an expression of the right length, which looks great:

```
{With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]],
With[{St=dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]]},CDexpr2[St,LD,hL]]/. LD->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,3]]/. hL->dataset2[[num]][[1;;All,4]]}
```

Now, all that I should need to do is replace all the `num`s in the above with `rules` -- I want to replace the 1st instance of `num` with 1, the 2nd instance of `num` with 2, and so on. I want the result to be a list of length `{11,14}`.

But when I apply `rules` like so:

```
MapThread[ReplaceAll, {list, rules}] // ReleaseHold
```

the result is a list of size `{11,14,14,14}` which means that it's not applying `rules` simultaneously, but instead it's applying them separately each time `num` shows up; but I would like for the `num`s to all be replaced by 1, then all be replaced by 2, and so on until the ones in the 11th element of list are replaced by 11.

I appreciate any help, and I'd be happy to provide some more context and details to help anyone reproduce this work!

Comment: `newlist = 
 Table[list /. rules[[n]], {n, 1, Length[rules], 1}] // ReleaseHold` may be doing what is required (??), but the resulting list is of dimensions {11,11}.

Comment: You have a data vector of 11 elements and you have 11 replacement rules. Where does the 14 come from? A bit of advice: try first a very small data set, e.g.2 elements, it is much easier to see what is going on.

Comment: @DanielHuber, 14 is one of the lengths of the data set. For example, dataset2[[1]][[1;;All,2]] has length 14. I found out a solution which I'll post as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this --- basically, using `CDexpr2[St, LD, hL]` and then replacing `LD` and `hL` with lists is a bad idea. It's much better to use `MapThread` to map the function `CDexpr2` over the relevant lists. The final form I ended up using is something like this:

```
list=ConstantArray[
 HoldForm[MapThread[
     CDexpr2, {dataset2[[1]][[;; , 2]], dataset2[[num]][[;; , 3]], 
      dataset[[num]][[;; , 4]]}]]], 11]
```

And on this `list`, using `MapThread` a second time works:

```
MapThread[ReplaceAll,{list,rules}]//ReleaseHold
```

and has the right dimensions, `{11,14}`